# JQuery: не срабатывает функция смены cheked после нескольких нажатий

Tags: jquery, checkbox, html, javascript

имеется кнопка и чекбоксом

```
    <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <input id="srcname" type="checkbox">
          </span>
  <input type="button" onclick="checkb()" value="ИМЯ" class="form-control">
</div><!-- /input-group -->
```

почему не срабатывает функция после нескольких нажатий?

```
function checkb(){

    var ch_status=$("#srcname").prop("checked");
    if(ch_status==false){
        $("#srcname").attr("checked","checked");
    }
    else{
        $("#srcname").removeAttr("checked");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

немного сумбурно вопрос задан, но если я правильно понял, то нужно ставить или убирать галку в зависимости от ее текущего состояния?

```
function checkb(){
    var $chkBx = $("#srcname");
    $chkBx.prop("checked", !$chkBx.is(":checked"));
}
```

[пример на JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xm9tj9w/)